# Factor integer for $3598057$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

> if you know that $n=3598057$ is product of two prime distinct numbers and also that $20779$ is root from $1$ mod $n$, find factor integer for $n$.

From [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity_modulo_n) I expected that
$$20779^2 \equiv 1 \mod n$$
But I checked in calculator that

$$20779^2 \equiv 0 \mod n$$
So I am not sure if I have understood this term correctly.

### Update

I tried to delete this question on phone (During writing this post I didn't have access to pc). But now, when there is a answer, I decided to mark as the best contributor and left this task for future readers. Exactly, my phone hasn't got a proper precision for numbers like that.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=20779%5E2+mod+3598057) says it's $1$

Comment: I checked in calculator of phone. Maybe it truncates digits... Sorry.

Comment: $20778=6\times3463; 20780=20\times1039$; $3598057=3463\times1039$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$20779^2 \equiv 1 \pmod {3598057}$ so

$20779^2 -1 \equiv 0 \pmod{3598057}$

$(20779-1)(20779+1) \equiv 0 \pmod {3598057}$

SO $3598057| 20778*20780$ so the prime factors of $3598057$ are among the prime factors of $20778$ and $20780$.

So $20778 = 6*3463$ and $20780 = 20*1039$.

$6$ and $20$ are clearly relatively prime to $3598057$ so the two prime factors of $3598057$ must be among the prime factors of $3463$ and $1039$.

It's within the realm of reasonability (I guess) to check that $3463$ and $1039$ are prime and that $3463*1039=3598057$.

....  That is, if we were *told* all those thing. (That $20779$ is square root of $1\pmod{3598057}$ and that $598057$ is the product of two primes.)  Not sure how you'd be expected to know that without guidance.

Comment: And if you don't want to factor $20778$ and $20780$, you can compute $\gcd(20778,3598057)$ and $\gcd(20780,3598057)$ using the Euclidean Algorithm, and get factors of $3598057$ that way.

Comment: Well, sure I guess.  Easy to see that $20778$ is even and by rule of $3$ divisible by $6$, and that $20780$ is divisible by $20$.  But yeah. ...